# How to get an UTC date string in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, utc

I am trying to get utc date string as "YYYYMMDD"

For now I do the following,

```
nowTime =  time.gmtime();
nowDate = date(nowTime.tm_year, nowTime.tm_mon, nowTime.tm_mday)
print nowDate.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

I used to do:

```
datetime.date.today().strftime()
```

but this gives me date string in local TZ

How can I get an UTC date string?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Or as Davidism pointed out, this would also work:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

I prefer the first approach, as it gets you in the habit of using timezone aware datetimes - but as J.F. Sebastian pointed out - it requires Python 3.2+.  The second approach will work in both 2.7 and 3.2 branches.