# How to get utc time from time string in python?

Tags: python, datetime, utc

In my application, i have two select options. one is for hour selection and another for minute selection. So when i fetch select option values i get values as time string like `'12:34'`. and I want to convert that time string to UTC time.

So, Can anyone please suggest me that how to get UTC time from timestring?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to know the timezone to calculate the UTC time; and also the format of the time (is it 24 hours - military time or 12 hours ie, AM/PM)?

Comment: Here  is a link [How to get an UTC date string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17822273/6521550) discussing similar concept.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid timeformat is 24 hours and about timezone, does python provide any functionality to get timezone info from system time?

Comment: @Nikunj yes it does, read the documentation please.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough information to do that because you need to know the offset of your timezone from UTC.

But to get you started

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
offset = -2 # I live in Central European Summer Time, so I am 2 hours east of UTC
myutctime = datetime.strptime(timestring,'%H:%M') + timedelta(hours=offset)
```